# BufferedReader vs. RandomAccessFile in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, bufferedreader, readline

I'm writing a small application in java

I read text files in various sizes and I need to read them line by line (and insert the line into array).
Is there difference between `BufferedReader.ReadLine()` and `RandomAccessFile.ReadLine()`, in terms of performance?

Is there any reason to prefer one or the other?

Comment: *"`BufferedReader.ReadLine()` and `RandomAccessFile.ReadLine()`"*  Given that neither method exists, they are quite similar.  ;)

Comment: Yes you are right but I figured people will understand my intention:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RandomAccessFile.readLine() might be slightly faster because it ignores character encoding. However it doesn't use buffering and still use StringBuffer :P so it could be slower on your system.

BufferedReader.readLine() is preferred because it handles character encoding e.g. UTF-8 or Windows-1252.

There is also a DataInputStream.readLine() which can be used with BufferedInputStream. Only use this is you can be sure you want ISO-8859-1 or ASCII encoding.

Comment: What about buffer usage, somebody wrote that BufferedReader might be faster because it uses buffer and RandomAccessFile not, is it true?

Comment: Good point, I may have been confused with DataInputStream + BufferedInputStream.

Comment: @choppy Yes, that's true. BufferedReader reads characters from the specified stream and stores them in a buffer. This increases the rate at which input is read.